# Switching hosting, keeping mx records

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, mx-record

Nice to meet you all!

Here is my dilemma:
I have to move a website to another hosting but keep the domain. The client currently has email set up with google apps and the mx records are set up accordingly on the old server.

This person cannot afford to wait a few hours for the mx records to propagate when I make the change to the new hosting. I am wondering if first I can set up the mx records on the new hosting and after a few hours set up the new nameservers for the domain to point to the new hosting.

Until the new nameservers propagate the email will work through the old hosting, but when they do propagate, will the e-mail go through the already set mx-records or do I have to wait for the mx-records to propagate also?

Note: I will be setting the same mx-records as they were set for the old server.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you are transferring your domain name to another registrar right? If so you may contact your new registrar tech support to give you access to upload all zone record before final cutover. Also registrar have a way to reduce the refresh time of your zone record which will take care of your downtime. I did the same for my domain  and downtime was zero. If your registrar remains same then there will not be any issue if you switch hosting only you need to change the pointers for your hosting record not MX record.

Comment: Are the IP's for the MX records changing (are you using new mail servers or just changing your DNS provider)? If they don't change you don't have to do anything since either way the senders will resolve the right mail server addresses.

Comment: I'm changing the dns server, not the registrar. The registrar and the domain remain the same. But that means I have to change the mx-records with the new dns provider. I was just hoping there will be no temporary bouncing of e-mails if I set the mx-records for the new dns server before changing the nameservers to the new dns server.

Comment: You say "I have to move a website to another hosting but keep the domain" but then you say "I'm changing the dns server, not the registrar". Are you moving the web hosting to another web hosting provider? If so, why are you mucking with the MX record at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the MX record's values are not going to change (they provide the same IP address as the mail server) then it does not matter, as long as the TTL on the MX records is longer than you expect the time for the new record to propagate you are set - either way the sending system will get the same information.